# Pulp not responding

Tags: python, pulp

I'm trying to use pulp' GLPK solver to solve VRP with additional time cost at each node, which is added directly to the travel time matrix. Here is the code with the constraints to ensure each customer is visited once by 1 staff and all route for each staff start and end at node 0.

```
import pulp
from pulp import LpMaximize, LpProblem, LpStatus, lpSum, LpVariable, LpMinimize, LpBinary, LpInteger, GLPK
input = []
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        input.append(line)

n = [int(x) for x in input[0].split()]
N = n[0]
K = n[1]
c = [int(x) for x in input[1].split()]
c.insert(0, 0)
poi_ma = []
for i in range(N+1):
    #poi_ma.append([int(x) for x in input().split()])
    poi_ma.append([int(x) for x in input[i+2].split()])
    for y in range(0, N + 1):
        if y == i:
            continue
        else:
            poi_ma[i][y] = poi_ma[i][y] + c[y]

model = LpProblem("myprob",sense=LpMinimize)
X =[]
X.append(0)
for k in range(1, K+1):
    X.append([])
    for i in range(N+1):
        X[k].append([])
        X[k][i] = []
        for j in range(N+1):
            x = LpVariable(f"X[{k}][{i}][{j}]", cat=LpBinary)
            X[k][i].append(x)
y = LpVariable("y", cat= LpInteger)
# Objective function: minimize the maximum work time
model += y

# Constraints:
# - Each customer is served by exactly one staff member
for j in range(N+1):
    for i in range(N+1):
        tmp = []
        for k in range(1, K+1):
            tmp.append(X[k][i][j])
    model += (lpSum(tmp) == 1)

# - Each staff member starts and ends at the headquarters
for k in range(1, K+1):
    tmp1 = []
    tmp2 = []
    for i in range(N+1):
        tmp1.append(X[k][0][i])
        tmp2.append(X[k][i][0])
    model += (lpSum(tmp1) == 1)
    model += (lpSum(tmp2) == 1)
"""
# - Enforce flow conservation at each customer location
for k in range(1, K+1):
    for i in range(N + 1):
        if i != N :  # Not the ending headquarters
            model += (lpSum([X[k][i][j] for j in range(N + 1)]) - lpSum([X[k][i][j] for i in range(N + 1)]) == 0)
"""
# - Calculate work time for each staff member and ensure it's less than or equal to y
for k in range(1, K+1):
    work_time = lpSum([poi_ma[i][j] * X[k][i][j] for i in range(N + 1) for j in range(N + 1) if i != j])
    model += (work_time <= y)

# Solve using branch and cut
status = model.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=False, cuts=True))  # Enable cuts for branch and cut

# Extract the solution
if model.status == 1:
    staff_schedules = []
    for k in range(1, K+1):
        visited = [0]  # Start at headquarters
        while visited[-1] != N + 1:  # Keep going until ending headquarters
            for j in range(N + 1):
                if X[k][visited[-1]][j].varValue == 1:
                    visited.append(j)
                    break
        staff_schedules.append(visited[1:-1])  # Remove headquarters from schedule
else:
    print("not")
    

print(K)
for k, schedule in enumerate(staff_schedules):
    print(len(schedule))
    print(*schedule)
```

the "test.txt" file contains:

```
5 2
6 8 7 1 9
0 5 10 6 4 8
5 0 5 4 2 6
10 5 0 5 7 4
6 4 5 0 6 2
4 2 7 6 0 8
8 6 4 2 8 0
```

However, when i execute the code, the terminal froze without any result from the program, i tried running another sample code and confirmed that pulp is installed and working find on my device. Can anyone help me identify the problem here ?

Comment: Hi there. You should probably work a bit more on isolating where the freeze happens. If small samples work, that's great; but do those samples use the same underlying solver? I'd start small, then slowly build toward the full solution, so that you know exactly when the freeze happens.